# bind values to application.hbs from different routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In Ember.js (**version 2.5.1**), I have the following code in my **application.hbs**:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            {{title}}<small>{{description}}</small>
        </h1>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        {{outlet}}
    </section>
</div>
```

Where should I declare `{{title}}` and `{{description}}` properties so they can change depending on the current route? I thought of generating an application controller (`ember g controller application`) which works fine for the index route, however, I am unable to change these properties if I navigate to other routes in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would design my application.hbs like this

```
    {{partial "app_navbar"}}
        <div class="container">
           {{outlet}}
        </div>
    {{partial "app_footer"}}
```

And to create a route dependent header i would make a component *content-header*

*templates/components/content-header.hbs*

```
<div class="content-header">
   <h1> {{params.title}} - <small> {{params.description}} </small> </h1>
</div>
```

And in your custom route's controllers

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    navbarParams: {
       title: 'Foo',
       description: 'Bar'
    }
});
```

And in your custom route's template

```
{{content-header params=navbarParams}}

{{! Your other content here}}
```

Comment: @kristjan-reinholdkri I did design the app with components instead of partials so my application.hbs does have things like {{page-footer}} for instance. I tried this approach and it didn't work (i can see the values for navbarParams on ember inspector but it doesn't get rendered). Care to post a https://ember-twiddle.com for me?

Comment: I managed to fix it but moving {{content-header}} from application.hbs into the route's template as you mentioned. But this is repetitive, I would like to have {{content-header}} in my application.hbs. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @AndreGallo But then what happens if there's a subroute and you dont need that "header" ?

Comment: All routes will need the header for now. But I see your point. This may impact when I introduce the concept of authenticated and non-aunthenticated routes. I have been googling for days now and haven't found a solution for ember 2.5. All answers seem to target old versions of ember.

Comment: @AndreGallo sry for the previous answer dunno what i was thinking lel.

Comment: @AndreGallo TBH i don't think there's a solution you're looking for. One way would be to inject application controller to each route and do the thing with "modules" but this is more hacky than adding the component to each route's template. we're actually using this approach and it's not that annoying (workin on a huge ember app).

Comment: I think I agree with you now. Better to keep things simple. You might want to update the answer so we don't leave code that doesn't really work and I'll accept your answer based on your last comment above. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @AndreGallo Yeah i deleted the modules answer.